# IDTExtensibility2 Add-In only Loads in Outlook

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-office, office-addins

I created a com add-in which is set to load on startup of Word, Excel and Outlook. When I attempt to debug the add-in  the OnConnection event is only fired in Outlook, never for word or excel. With a compiled version I can see, via procmon, the Load Behaviour being changed from 3 to 2 in word and excel, but no real clue as to a reason why. Nothing actually happens in the add-in at the moment other than the default code as inserted by the create project wizard, so I can exclude an unhandled exception in my code.

Can anyone help?

I have also removed the shim to eliminate that as a cause

Comment: Be sure you check out [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com) as an alternative to AddIn projects in VS. This solves many issues if you're serving multiple office versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the unlikely event anyone else is still writing these, this was the cause as I was targeting a Office 2000 products, it appears that this doesn't affect Outlook!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948461

Specifically the **"Clients that are running Office 2000 or Office XP"** section.